# Execute method before form submitted

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following code to submit a form with a hidden value.

The problem is - I can't set the value of `MyNewValue` before the form is submitted to the remote address `https://some-remote-site/Form.aspx`.

Does anybody know how I can set the hidden value when the user clicks the button and then submit the form to the same address?

MyFile.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="height: 370px">    
    <form id="myForm" method="post" runat="server" action="https://some-remote-site/Form.aspx">
        <fieldset>
            <asp:HiddenField id="MyNewValue" Value="X" runat="server" />
            <p>
                <label for="Username">Username:</label>
                <asp:TextBox id="Username" Text="Username" runat="server" />
            </p>
            <asp:Button ID="SubmitForm" runat="server" onclick="SubmitForm_Click" Text="Button" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

MyFile.aspx.cs

```
// Not executed because action="https://some-remote-site/Form.aspx" is set
protected void SubmitForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyNewValue.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it client-side using jQuery. So when the user clicks submit, and before submitting the form, you can update your hidden input and then return true to proceed the submission of your form.

This is it could be done:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(){
        $('#MyNewValue').val('YOUR_VALUE');
        return true;
    })
});
```

Comment: would be more acceptable of an answer to say it can be done client-side.  jQuery being a good framework and example to that notion.

Comment: I think Brett's comment was more of a prompt to fill out the answer with a bit more content.  Yes your code works, but it is useful to add some information about why and how so that people learn rather than just copy-paste answers.  Good answers are teaching moments :)